# Understanding Leela Chess Zero (Lc0) "verbose-move-stats output"

Tags: uci, alphazero, leela

I'm trying to fully understand the Leela's [verbose-move-stats output](https://lczero.org/dev/wiki/technical-explanation-of-leela-chess-zero/#example---verbose-move-stats-output):

[image: Lc0 verbose-move-stats output]

Are the statements below correct?

1. The move that will be played is `e2e4`, since it's the one with the greatest count of visits (`N: 128`).
2. It also happens to have the greatest probability of being the best (`P: 10.01%`), the best single-node evaluation (`V: 0.0556`) and the best average child nodes evaluation (`Q: 0.05778`).
3. However, if the search continues, then the next node to be visited at this level of the tree will be `b1a3`, because it has the best PUCT score (`Q+U: 0.11467`).
4. The number `+63` besides the visit count of `e2e4` is the win/draw/loss combined score of playout simulated games, such as in `+95/1/-32`.

Also, I have some questions:

5. When/where will the playout score be used by the searching algorithm? I don't see it in the PUCT formula.
6. What is the `332` number beside `e2e4`? Is it just a move index?